# Explicitly passing argument to local action for access check

Tags: 8, nodes, routes, group

I'm using the group module, and in a custom module I'm trying to create a local task that will bring you directly to the create page for a particular group content type. My goal is to skip the create page where you select the content type.

I've defined a local task:

```
entity.group_content.create_form:
  route_name: entity.group_content.create_form
  title: 'Add new service'
  defaults:
    plugin_id: group_node:service
  appears_on:
    - 'view.group_services.page_1'
```

It doesn't complain about passing the `$group` for the access check, which I'm assuming is being successfully passed due to query magic. Where it breaks down is on `$plugin_id` on the access check with the error.

> RuntimeException: Callable "Drupal\group\Access\GroupContentCreateEntityAccessCheck::access" requires a value for the "$plugin_id" argument. in Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument() (line 142 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).

As an example, the route I'm trying to provide would end up being:

/group/{group}/content/create/{plugin_id}

aka

/group/1/content/create/group_node%3Aservice

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question. The key is that we are working with route parameters,  not route options which are akin to `l()` in Drupal 7.

This [article](https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/drupal-8-how-to-create-the-local-tasks-through-custom-module) goes into more detail. Here is the important part:

```yml
# yaml file to define one or more local task(s).
#
# Definitions can contain any of the following:
# title: (required) The untranslated title of the menu link.
# description: The untranslated description of the link.
# route_name: (optional) The route name to be used to build the path. Either a
#   route_name or a link_path must be provided.
# base_route: Used to group together related tabs.
# parent_id: Use the parent_id to relate a tab to a parent tab for multiple
#   levels of tabs.
# route_parameters: (optional) The route parameters to build the path. An array.
# link_path: (optional) If you have an external link use link_path instead of
#   providing a route_name.
# weight: (optional) An integer that determines the relative position of items
#   in the menu; higher-weighted items sink. Defaults to 0.
#   Menu items with the same weight are ordered alphabetically.
# options: (optional) An array of options to be passed to l() when generating
#   a link from this menu item.
```

So my action routing file is updated:

```yml
entity.group_content.create_form:
  route_name: entity.group_content.create_form
  title: 'Add new service'
#  defaults:
  route_parameters:
    plugin_id: group_node:BUNDLE
  appears_on:
    - 'view.group_services.page_1'
```

Be sure to replace *BUNDLE* with the content type machine name you would like to pass.

Flush caches.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer! Just adding that under the `plugin_id: group_node:service`, `service` should be replaced by the content type machine name.

Comment: @jozi Yes, you are correct, sorry that was confusing! "service" was my machine name. I've clarified the answer.